# Defining variable after assigning them value in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, scope, global-variables

I get this out put

```
=============================== RESTART: Shell ===============================
>>> 
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "E:/Python/Roy Progs/test.py", line 2
    global x
SyntaxWarning: name 'x' is assigned to before global declaration
>>> 
==================== RESTART: E:/Python/Roy Progs/test.py ====================
10
>>>
```

when I run this code.

```
x=5
global x
x=10
print x
```

Yes I know that defining a variable after assigning it a value is absurd, however python seems to understand the code.
I have 2 questions:
1) Why does Python give a warning and not an error.
2) why is there a restart after the warning message.

It would be helpful to know how exactly python is interpreting this code.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Do not post screenshots of code. Paste your code into a code block use the `{}` button on the toolbar when [edit]ing your post.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I didn't know that it was to be done this way.

Comment: The same goes for the interpreter, this should also be cut & pasted. Also, for multiline code use a code block, rather than back-ticks.

Comment: Then when should I post a screen shot?

Comment: Never, for text. If you have a picture that cannot be simply pasted as text, then fine, but for this you should not. Screenshots of text are *very* hard to read, and impossible to copy text out of for people who are trying to run your code to see what your problem is. For a simple situation like yours, the second reason is less important, but the first still holds. See [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) meta post